# Layout is broken after login or logout, Laravel and Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I am developing an application using Vue.js and Laravel JetStream. My problem is that when i login the layout of the main page is broken and after the refresh it fixes:

[image]

This is how it should look:

[image]

This also happens when I logout from this layout, If I login and land on another page the layout loads correctly. I checked the network data on Chrome and the problem is that it doesn't load the css and js at all. I don't know why it happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How and where are you including your css and js that's not loading?

Comment: It is not loading any css

Comment: Understood, but where the ```link``` or ```script``` tags? Can you include your ```app.blade.php``` file?